# Azure Application Gateway : 502 error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to figure out 502 error on my application gateway. My VM is configured to use https and I am able to connect to it directly but when the same is connected through app gateway I am getting 502 error. I am not able to figure health probe. Suppose my VM has IP1 as ip and "/path/try.htm" so that I can traverse to http://ip1/path/try.htm now I want to use this link as target for health probe. You can consider ip of appgw as IP2 if it is required anywhere ?

Appreciate any help.

Update : Trying this [Application Gateway - 502 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046056/application-gateway-502-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Authentication Certificate used in the Application Gateway Backend HTTP Settings should be the public key of the .pfx certificate present on the backend server. Only then will this whitelist the backend with the Application Gateway.
Reference article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell

For SSL Certificate for HTTPS website: https://www.ssl.com/guide/ssl-best-practices-a-quick-and-dirty-guide/

Configure the application gateway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview

Additional: If you are sending more than 2000 requests you may see lot of 502 errors.

Comment: my backend user ,cer certificate and I thought That is required!!! I am a newbie when SSL is concerned.